# Not the same PostgreSQL database size on master/slave!

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a PostgreSQL database 9.4.4 on redhat 6.6 in streaming replication. The problem that I don't have the same database pretty-size on master and slave. The database size on slave is almost two times bigger than the master database.
Have you any idea about this case?

Thank you for answering. The problem that I had the same difference whith "linux command "du" and database searching informations.

I have these results:

```
[master:postgres:]$du -k $PGDATA
...
2387924 /pgqdata/pgambari/data
[slave:postgres:]$du -k $PGDATA
...
4059916 /pgqdata/pgambari/data

[master:postgres:]$psql -c "SELECT pg_database.datname as "database_name", pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)) AS size_in_mb FROM pg_database ORDER by size_in_mb DESC;"
 database_name | size_in_mb
---------------+------------
 pgrepmon      | 7123 kB
 postgres      | 7027 kB
 template1     | 6971 kB
 template0     | 6843 kB
 ambari        | 2007 MB
(5 rows)

[slave:postgres:]$psql -c "SELECT pg_database.datname as "database_name", pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)) AS size_in_mb FROM pg_database ORDER by size_in_mb DESC;"
 database_name | size_in_mb
---------------+------------
 pgrepmon      | 7131 kB
 postgres      | 7027 kB
 template1     | 6971 kB
 template0     | 6729 kB
 ambari        | 3645 MB --<< HERE
(5 rows)
```

Comment: did you check the size in the database (using a select on pg_database) or in the file system (using du)? In certain situations the results may differ - especially a special use of symlinks and tablespaces may lead to double counting in the dictionary views, while the OS tools should tell you the correct size.

Comment: strange indeed. What do you see in the subfolders under pgdata: do they have the same size on both sides or is the duplication effects visible there too?

Comment: What do you get for `select sum(relpages)*8/1024 from pg_class` when logged into the ambari database (on each system)?

Comment: (Slave)ambari=# select sum(relpages)*8/1024 from pg_class;
 ?column?
----------
     1919
(1 row)
===========Masterambari=# select sum(relpages)*8/1024 from pg_class;
 ?column?
----------
     1919
(1 row)

Comment: So i have the same value.

Comment: If the database was recently vacuumed yet sum(relpages) substantially disagrees with pg_database_size(), that suggests that some files not under PostgreSQL's control got stuffed into the directory base/<databaseOID>/ (assuming you aren't using non-default table spaces).  You should get a listing of that directory on search server and compare them.

Comment: It's exact i hase almost the double of files on Slave:                                                                                                               [Slave:postgres]$pwd && ls -al | wc -l
/pgqdata/pgambari/data/tbs_ambari/PG_9.4_201409291/16396
1387
[Master:postgres]$pwd && ls -al | wc -l
/pgqdata/pgambari/data/tbs_ambari/PG_9.4_201409291/16396
725                                                                                                                   1387 files VS 725 files. So what should i do to resolve this problem please.